# Possible to upload to a style library remotely using client context?

Tags: client-object-model, style-library

As title says. I have a win forms app that connects to a remote SharePoint instance using the client context. How can I now, programmatically, upload a file to this style library and what permissions must I take into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have contribute permission for this library, and use client object model.

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://yoursitecollection"))
{
      Web web = clientContext.Web;
      List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Style library");               

      FileCreationInformation fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();                  

      byte[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\TestFile.txt");
      fileCreationInformation.Content = file;
      fileCreationInformation.Url = @"http://yoursitecollection/Style library/TestFile.txt";              

      list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);

      clientContext.Load(list);
      clientContext.ExecuteQuery();        
}
```